# How to set Rollback in case of Error in Talend?

Tags: sql-server, talend

I have a Talend Project, that Synchronize two tables by :

1. `DELETE TABLE 1`
2. `SELECT * TABLE 2`
3. `INSERT TABLE 1`

look at photo down below.

Imagine, two first steps go fine, but at final step (insertion) it throws an error. Can I restore deleted rows, that were executed on the very first step?

And how `tMSSqlRollback` works anyway? I tried in vain to set it up. (There're no components in "List of components" drop down list, in 'Simple parameter' tab.

[image: Talend project photo]

Comment: In tMysqlDB components you should use same connection throughout and this connection tmysqlconnection should not have auto commit enabled (under advance settings). Every mysql db component in your job should not create a new inbuilt connection but should use existing connection. this way it should work, else in your case since you are using tmysqlrow to write delete - you can create a temporrary table to store your table data before deleting it, and incase of error or failure, you can copy back the data from this backup/temporary table into your table from which you were deleting this data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, as garpitmzn said, you should open a connection with the corresponding element for your database type, say *tMySQLConnection*. This could be done with a *tPreJob*. Now, also add a *tMySQLCommit* in a *tPostJob*.

You want to add some error handling. There are two ways

- `Extended inserts` is activated for *tMySQLOutput*: You would have to add a *tLogRowCatcher* somewhere outside your job. Add a *tRollback* for your database type directly after it (like with the *tPre/tPostJob*, link it with *OnComponentOk*).
- `Extended inserts` is deactivated: Additionally to *Main*, you also can connect per right click *Recjected*. Those rows are rejected for some reason. You can collect these records and store them in a table or some kind of error reporting where you handle those rejected rows. *NOTE:* This way, although more detailed, can be very very bad on performance. Also, if the database connection crashes or something else is wrong, you still would need a *tLogRowCatcher*

The rollback component doesn't need to be part of the main job.